# Inconsistencies in Amazon web scraping using bs4

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am scraping the amazon next page links by finding the html of the next page from the current page. I am using Beautifulsoup for this purpose. There are total 20 pages. But when I ran my python script, sometimes the script(scraper) gives me links of first 16 pages, sometimes It gives me links of first 15 pages, and sometimes it gives me links of all 20 pages. why is that so? What is the solution for that? Thanks

Comment: You have to share the code you are using, so we can help you, we don't know how to read minds yet!